# redraw a custom UIVIEW when device orientation changed SWIFT 5

Tags: swift

I wrote the code down for new UIVIEW but after device rotation the draw of UIVIEW do not get cleaned up for new situation! And stay visible for user! look at picture. how we can fix the problem?

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {

        var drawView = UIView()

        let drawViewOffsetFromTop = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.top ) )
        let drawViewOffsetFromBottom = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.bottom ) )
        
        let drawViewWidth = Int( view.frame.size.width ) - 2*25
        let drawViewHeight = Int( view.frame.size.height) - drawViewOffsetFromTop - drawViewOffsetFromBottom

        drawView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25 , y: drawViewOffsetFromTop, width: drawViewWidth  , height: drawViewHeight ))
        drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        drawView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.addSubview(drawView)
   
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Autolayout** to make things simple.

Remove override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` completely.

Use the following in `viewDidLoad`

```swift
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var drawView = UIView()

    //Setup Constraints for `drawView`
    drawView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        drawView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
        drawView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
        drawView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 15),
        drawView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -15)
    ])

}
```

**Edit**: Solution without Autolayout

The issue is that your drawView is added multiple times in the view hierarchy! You can just add it once and only change the frame.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    var drawView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(drawView)
        drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        drawView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {


        let drawViewOffsetFromTop = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.top ) )
        let drawViewOffsetFromBottom = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.bottom ) )
        
        let drawViewWidth = Int( view.frame.size.width ) - 2*25
        let drawViewHeight = Int( view.frame.size.height) - drawViewOffsetFromTop - drawViewOffsetFromBottom
        
        drawView.frame = CGRect(x: 25 , y: drawViewOffsetFromTop, width: drawViewWidth  , height: drawViewHeight )

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! But your code is not the answer of question, I could use your codes at first place before asking my question here! the all point of this question is not using constraint! But making a fresh draw of view! of curse getting rid of old view in new orientation! But I present your time and code!

Comment: Oh alright. The issue is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times for a view controller. Each time it is called, a new view is added to your view hierarchy but the views you are adding is never removed. You can initialize `drawView` in your view controller instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, add it as a subView in `viewDidLoad` so that there is only 1 `drawView` at a time and only set the frame when needed!

Comment: Try initializing drawView and add it as a subView in `viewDidLoad` and only change the frame when needed :) 
You could put the change of frame in an animation block as well so it shows a graceful change of frame in UI.

Comment: I am using viewDidLayoutSubviews because of safeAreaInsets! If I use viewDidLoad, then I could have zero value for safeAreaInsets! that is why I am using viewDidLayoutSubviews! Also your code would get problem in Landscape mode! because of notch! Have you seen the screen on Landscape mode? I can solve my question with adding a new full view background on top of old draw and draw the new view! but I was interested to find out better way

Comment: You can still use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set the frame of `drawView`. The point I was trying to make is, you are adding new views to your view hierarchy every time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called(it can be called multiple times). So just add the view once and change the frame alone in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if you wish. Use `drawView.frame = //your frame`

Comment: Let me edit the solution so I can explain 5 mins. Please check now :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **not** put creating UIView code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,  create and add it in `viewDidLoad` instead. You can put view frame update code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

The problem is you are adding `drawView` multiple times without removing existing ones. In addition you are initializing `drawView` multiple times in different lines unnecessarily.

To fix the problem, create `drawView` in your controller, add it to superview in `viewDidLoad` and edit your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` just like below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var drawView : UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(drawView)
    }    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let drawViewOffsetFromTop = max(25 , Int(view.safeAreaInsets.top))
        let drawViewOffsetFromBottom = max(25 , Int(view.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
        
        let drawViewWidth = Int(view.frame.size.width ) - 2*25
        let drawViewHeight = Int(view.frame.size.height) - drawViewOffsetFromTop - drawViewOffsetFromBottom

        drawView.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: drawViewOffsetFromTop, width: drawViewWidth, height: drawViewHeight)
        drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        drawView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
}
```

Comment: I already explained to  @Rishabh why I can not use viewDidLoad()! you said put my code in viewDidLoad() and then trigger viewDidLoad() from  viewDidLayoutSubviews(). So I did I does not help! have tried your idea? And Yes! every time I do draw a fresh view in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). How ever I solved the  problem by paining of full screen and redraw it again!

Comment: Yes i tried the solution i wrote, and see problem was fixed. Did you? You should add subview once, then edit  layout in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Otherwise there are multiple views unnecessarily even you don't see it. You can inspect the views you added using *Debug View Hierarchy*

Comment: no! I think it is not right! As @Rishabh said! viewDidLayoutSubviews is just for draw without make it editable! but with viewDidLoad we can edit it! the problem with viewDidLoad is about notch! I do not have access to safeAreaInsets from viewDidLoad. As I said there is no way to delete or dismiss an added view to Subview! the only way is cover it! It will be very very handy when you are drawing Gradient! when you change your orientation it would be same problem with Gradient! THE BEST WAY cover it and redraw!

Answer (score -1):

```
//▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
var drawView = UIView()
//▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼


//█ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}
//█ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █



//█ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{

    //▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
    let backView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width  , height: view.frame.size.height ))
    backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    view.addSubview(backView)
    //▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼


    //▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
    let drawViewOffsetFromTop = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.top ) )
    let drawViewOffsetFromBottom = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.bottom ) )
    let drawViewOffsetFromRight = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.right ) )
    let drawViewOffsetFromLeft = max( 25 , Int( view.safeAreaInsets.left ) )
    //▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
    

    //▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
    let drawViewWidth = Int( view.frame.size.width ) - drawViewOffsetFromRight - drawViewOffsetFromLeft
    let drawViewHeight =  Int( view.frame.size.height) - drawViewOffsetFromTop - drawViewOffsetFromBottom
    //▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
    
    //▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
    drawView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: drawViewOffsetFromRight , y: drawViewOffsetFromTop, width: drawViewWidth  , height: drawViewHeight ))
    //▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼

    
    //▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
    drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
    drawView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    drawView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    drawView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.addSubview(drawView)
    //▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼

    

    

}
//█ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █
```